# How can I aggregate a count of rows by time intervals in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a PostgreSQL table that has columns for datetime and for an array of items, such as:

```
| time                       | items                  |
| -------------------------- | ---------------------- |
| 2020-12-06 11:31:38.000    |  {item1, item2}        |
| 2020-12-06 11:48:11.304    |  {item1}               |
| 2020-12-06 11:48:48.654    |  {item1, item2, item3} |
| 2020-12-06 11:49:50.355    |  {item2}               |
| 2020-12-06 11:55:31.842    |  {item1, item2}        |
```

How can I query the table to aggregate the count of a specific item in equidistant time intervals?

For example, I'd like to count the occurrences of `item1` in 5 minute intervals, so that the query result looks like this:

```
| start_time                 | end_time                            | item1 count     |
| -------------------------- | ----------------------------------- | --------------- |
| 2020-12-06 11:30:00.000    |  2020-12-06 11:34:99.999            |       1         |
| 2020-12-06 11:35:00.000    |  2020-12-06 11:39:99.999            |       0         |
| 2020-12-06 11:40:00.000    |  2020-12-06 11:44:99.999            |       0         |
| 2020-12-06 11:45:00.000    |  2020-12-06 11:49:99.999            |       2         |
| 2020-12-06 11:50:00.000    |  2020-12-06 11:54:99.999            |       0         |
| 2020-12-06 11:55:00.000    |  2020-12-06 11:59:99.999            |       1         |
```

I'm having a tough time trying to figure out what query can help me achieve this in the most optimal way. I've been thinking that Postgres' `date_trunc` or `grid` might help with this, but am really not sure how to approach the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: A five minute interval can be anchored anywhere, so do you want it starting on the hour or some other starting point?

Comment: Arbitrary starting point was what I was going for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate the timestamps.  Then unnest, filter and aggregate:

```
select gs.ts, count(i.time) as num_item1
from generate_series('2020-12-06 11:30:00.000'::timestamp, '2020-12-06 11:55:00.000', interval '5 minute') gs(ts) left join
     (items i join lateral
      unnest(i.items) item
      on item = 'item1'
     )
     on i.time >= gs.ts and i.time < gs.ts + interval '5 minute'
group by gs.ts
order by 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9451e2a2c1d521964ff89dd91ea7cf3d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Works great, you're a wizard! Minor question: if I needed to further filter my query by some additional column, could I simply do something like `on item = 'item1' and otherColumn = 'someValue'`?

Comment: @user12533955 . . . I think that will work.